# How do I combine @PathParams and @RequestBody properly?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In my Spring MVC Controller I am trying to map incomming parameters to an object. My controller currently looks like this.:

```
@RestController("fundsConfirmationController")
@RequestMapping("/accounts/{accountId}/funds-confirmations")
public class FundsConfirmationController {

@GetMapping(
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
public ResponseEntity<?> fundsConfirmation(@PathVariable("accountId") String accountId,
                                           @RequestBody FundsConfirmationRequestDTO fundsConfirmationRequestDTO) {

    System.out.println(accountId + " " + fundsConfirmationRequestDTO);

    return null;
}
```

As such I haven't found a way to properly combine `@PathVariable` and `@RequestBody` apart from setting the `accountId` seperatly in the method? (I can't change the incoming parameters as these are a predefined requirement.)

Is there a proper way of combining `@PathParams` and `@ResponseBody` in the same Object? Without to map the  Path Param in the DTO seperatly?

Any suggestion how to properly tackle this?

In case I am posting in the wrong place or I need to specify more details please correct me.

Thanks in advance, Tom

Comment: What's the point of sending a *RequestBody* to a `GET` request?

Comment: As per the design the extra parameters for the request are added in JSON to the request.
/accounts/{accountId}/funds-confirmations
{
 "amount":1234.34,
 "ccy":"EUR",
 "cardNumber":"1234",
 "payee":"Tom Br"
}

Comment: What's the question exactly?

Comment: Is there a proper way of combining 'PathParams' and 'ResponseBody' in the same Object? Without to map the  Path Param in the DTO seperatly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you use the GET method. If you want the requestBody to be used by Spring you want to use the POST method. With the GET method the body is just ignored.

See :

- [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)
- [Does Spring @RequestBody support the GET method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34956899/1140748)

Comment: Thanks for the input. The GET method was able to receive the @RequestBody. However by going through your resources I challenged the incoming setup of parameters. On the GET request they were converted from a JSON Payload to Query Parameters.