# How can I set an optional RequestBody field without it being deleted when I make the call?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a small program in spring-boot which through a get call having a @RequestBody returns me a message with all the specifications (in my case of cars)

```
public class CarsRequest implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String plate ;
    private  String price;
}
```

I would like to be able to make sure that if a field is set to null, it can still find the relative message with the other fields having a value, in my case, I wanted to put that the "name" field is optional in the RequestBody, is it possible to do this? I tried setting

```
    public CarsResponse getCars(@RequestBody (required = false) CarsRequest request) throws IOException {
           //some code 

   }
```

but then when I go to do the get it completely deletes the null field at the time of the get and therefore fails to do it

Comment: These are query params of the get url or what?

Comment: If your API's request method is GET, then note that GET methods does not have request bodies. Check here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34956992/3709922

Comment: @code_mechanic yes, these are the parameters

Comment: @Numero21 but why you are having them as body (object CarsRequest) and not function params ?

Comment: @code_mechanic brings up a good point. Are you sending JSON or form data? Also, what do you mean by _when I go to do the get_?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm sending a Json Body, I meant when I make the get call from Postman or from terminal

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `@RequestBody` annotation from the function and keep it as it is

```
public CarsResponse getCars(CarsRequest request) throws IOException {
           //some code 

}
```

Now all fields will be converted into query params and all will be optional, because query param by convention are optional

```
public class CarsRequest implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String plate ;
    private  String price;
}
```

And call like this

```
GET /someEndpoint?name=<value>&plate=null
```

But still if you want to make some params mandatory, then use `javax.annotations` or apply validation yourself.

**EDIT:** As asked in comment, if you are accepting JSON as parameter body then you can do one thing, you can accept it as String and then convert json to object inside function body

```
public CarsResponse getCars(@RequestParam(required = false) String request) throws IOException {
           ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
           CarRequest request = mapper.readValue(request,CarRequest.class);
          // other code

}
```

and call it something like this

```
GET /someEndpoint?request="{ \"name\" : null, \"plate\": \"someValue\" }"
```

**EDIT 2:**

You can do one more thing if you want to keep sending json and have it transformed into object, you can declare a binder something like this

```
// Some controller class
class SomeController {
   @Autowired
   ObjectMapper mapper;
   
   // Ommited methods here
   
    @GetMapping("/carRequest")
    public ResponseEntity<String> testBinder(@RequestParam CarRequest request) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("{\"success\": \"" + request.name+ "\"}");
    }

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(CarRequest.class, new CarRequestEditor(mapper));
    }

    static class CarRequestEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

        private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

        public CarRequestEditor(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
            this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        }

        @Override
        public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException 
        {
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
                setValue(new CarRequest());
            } else {
                try {
                    setValue(objectMapper.readValue(text, CarRequest.class));
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
   
}
```

Please note that the client need to send the json URL encoded like this

```
http://localhost:8180/carRequest?request=%7B%22name%22%3"test"%7D
```

Comment: But the author of question said they are parameters and not json body.

Comment: Hi @code_mechanic, For external reasons I have to keep the RequestBody with the Json body, isn't there a way to act without having to modify this part?

Comment: @Numero21 for that you would have to write custom PropertyEditor and bind it with your controller but that would convert every method call which is accepting json to the Object mentioned in function.

Comment: Could you give me an example of this Property Editor?

Comment: Need to check if it can be done with spring boot, in spring mvc it can be done easily.

Comment: Updated my answer, please check if works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a single field optional by making it an `Optional`, in your case  `Optional<String>`. If the field does not appear in the request body, then the `Optional` will be empty.

```
public class CarsRequest implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String plate;
    private Optional<String> price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are using @RequestBody (required = false) CarsRequest
that means your CarsRequest object itself is optional
rather than you can use

```
@NotEmpty 
private String plate ;
@NotEmpty
private  String price;
```