# Converting to List result in Java

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I have the following method:

```
public MenuExpandedDTO findMenuExp(UUID menuUuid) {
    final MenuDTO menu = menuService.findByUuid(menuUuid);
    final MenuPropertiesDTO propertiesDTO = new MenuPropertiesDTO(
            menu.getUuid(),
            menu.getName()
    );

    final List<GroupExpDTO> groups = menuGroupService
            .findAllByMenuUuid(menuUuid).stream()
            .map(menuGroup -> {
                UUID groupUuid = menuGroup.getGroupUuid();
                return findGroupExp(groupUuid);
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new MenuExpDTO(propertiesDTO, groups, null, null);
}
```

In this method, I pass a single `menuUuid` and then get combination of a single `MenuPropertiesDTO` and `List<GroupExpDTO>`.

I want to pass a `List<menuUuid>` instead of a single `menuUuid` and then get the result according to the uuids in this list. However, I am confused if there is  a proper way for this in Java. I think there is no need to use loop and it would be possible to evaluate this using `stream`. But  have really no idea how to construct it or if it is possible. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can create new method `public List<MenuExpandedDTO> findMenuExp(List<UUID> menuUuid) { return menuUuid.stream().map(this::findMenuExp).collect(Collectors.toList()); }`

Comment: *get the result according to the uuids in this list* - How should the result type look like? Is it a `Map<UUID, MenuExpandedDTO>` or a `List<MenuExpandedDTO>`?

Comment: @geobreze Thanks a lot for your help, but I am confused about the usage. On the other hand, should I change the group part? What about posting your suggestion as an answer?

Comment: @user7 I need to use `List<MenuExpandedDTO>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly from the question and comments, you need a method, which will work in the same manner, but for a list of UUIDs.

To achieve this, you can create new method, which will call the one you've implemented.

```java
public List<MenuExpandedDTO> findMenuExp(List<UUID> menuUuids) {
    return menuUuids.stream()
        // assuming this method is added to the same class, I'm referring 'this' here
        .map(this::findMenuExp)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This method will return of list having size equal to `menuUuids.size()` and `i`th element of `List<MenuExpandedDTO>` will correspond to `i`th element of `menuUuids` list.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your useful helps. I tried to apply this approach and I think it is a smarter solution. However, I have a little problem. Normally I pass a **selected** uuid to the Controller via `@PathVariable UUID menuUuid` in the Controller. But, I have no idea how I should pass multiple selected uuid to the Controller. Assume that I pass `List<UUID> menuUuid` to the Controller. Should I pass them as method parameter instead of `@PathVariable`?

Comment: @Henry, you can pass list even to `@PathVariable`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22298768/4655217. But if it's possible, I would recommend making it a query parameter for more clarity, since you can name you variable in pluar form explicitly saying that you're expecting list of ids.

Comment: I tried `@RequestParam List<UUID> menuUuid`, but it gives *"menuUuid parameter is missing"* error. I pass the value in Postman like `{ "menuItemUuid": ["6849bcbb-c26c-4299-9ca4-dcde56830f4e"] }`. So, should I use query parameter instead of `@RequestParam` for this scenario?

Comment: `@RequestParam` means query parameter, so you need to pass it like `http://your-api?menuUuid=uuid-1,uuid-2,uuid-3`. To pass it in the request body, you need to make your endpoint POST, and accept your DTO using `@RequestBody menuUuidDto`. And DTO will be java class `class MenuUuuidDto { List<UUID> menuItemUuid; }

Comment: Many thanks, voted up. Actually it seems to work if I pass the array values ad form data by separating comma. However, is there a proper way to pass them as json as I generally use in Postman? (I use `@RequestParam` ).

Comment: Spring discards response body for GET requests, so you need to make your request POST, for example. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34956992/4655217. And then you need to accept request body: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body#@requestbody. After that send request body via postman: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/requests/#raw-data

Comment: Thanks you very much for your helps. I marked it as answer and after try, I will ask additional question. Regards.