# Can I do a GET with request body in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, get

I'm using Spring Boot and Spring MVC and I need to make a GET with a request body. Is this possible?

I tried this but it's not working. I get 404.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/v1/foo")
    public ApiRes postBody(@RequestBody ApiReq apiReq) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It is possible to do so, but this is against HTTP design guidelines. If you are forced to use GET requests, I would recommend you use query parameters. Otherwise, use a POST request.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34956899/does-spring-requestbody-support-the-get-method Please check this out

Answer (score 4):

Technically it is possible but it is against the HTTP API Design Guidelines.
Request-Bodys should only be used for POST or PUT.

For further information: https://swagger.io/resources/articles/best-practices-in-api-design/

Comment: programs like Postman can send a GET request with a body, but basically - the browser can't / won't allow it

Comment: But i read the "Spring start here" book, which mention that before 2014, http protocol spec does not allow request body for GET.  But that changed in 2014.   Nevertheless, when i try it out in the latest version of spring, seems like it still does not allow